# Async or separate thread for TCP Client sending at high frequency

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

I'm working on a Xamarin iOS app that uses a gamepad, and pushes input to a server over a customer TCP based protocol of a rate of ~40 messages/s.

What would yield best app performance results; having a dedicated thread sending the messages, or using async/await like this: `await WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely pros and cons to using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This will allow work to return to any available thread, but involves additional overhead to `context-switch` threads.

However, if your messaging system is a fire-and-forget and your message is handled by some other process then `await`'ing your method is unnecessary.

`ConfigureAwait(true)` (default) can be better to avoid context-switching, remember these things are also hardware dependent.

This may be of better use: [When to use ConfigureAwait](http://www.msevestre.ca/when-to-use-configureawait-in-asynchronous-programming/)